# Google Script Project Across Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have had some success writing container-bound scripts to add custom functions to Google Sheets in the past. I am now at a point where I need to share these custom functions across a couple of sheets I'm managing and I thought that a script project was the best path to do that. So I created one and made two .gs files, one for the function itself and one to read in reference data. These scripts are working fine with hard coded values in the context of the script project.

After getting this working, I now need to access my function from a sheet or two and this is where I'm stuck. I cannot figure out how to "bind", "deploy", "attach" or otherwise "connect" the script project so when I try to use the custom formula, it works as if it were container-bound.

I am quite sure that this is a simple step I'm overlooking, but I got in a long argument with Google's AI last night about this and wound up closing my laptop on it after much frustration.

Here are the entities I'm working with:

Project at script.google.com: Tax Calculator

Files: readReferenceData.gs, getIncomeTax.gs

Function: CalculateIncomeTax() <<<--- this is what I need to see in Sheets. This custom formula is defined in the getIncomeTax.gs script. That script depends onthe readReferenceData.gs file to read in tax tables.

All of this is managed under my personal Google ID and all sheets and reference data sheets are maintained on my Google Drive.

So, what's the right way to gain access to these proejct-centric formulas?

Looking forward to the groups knowledge!

I thought after creating the script project I would be able to access my custom formulas in any of my sheets.

Comment: Try reading [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest) I don't know how to accomplish exactly what you wish but I this this is the beginning.  It could be a lot easier to use.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627408/how-to-sh

Answer (score 0):

[Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) may help you with this. Libraries allow you to create functions in one script project and reuse them in other container-bound and standalone script projects.

[Create and share](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#create_and_share_a_library) the project that contains functions you want to use elsewhere as a library.

Create a new deployment of your script.

[image]

And select **Library** as the type.

[image]

Get the script ID which you can find in the address bar of your browser.

[image]

From another script project, [add the library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project). Click **Libraries** from the side panel.

[image]

Enter the script ID. Then click **Lookup** and **Add**.

[image]

The library identifier (or namespace) is listed under Libraries. Type the library identifier in the editor, and autocomplete will display any methods or functions available from the library.

[image]

Using a library's custom formula as a formula in the local spreadsheet is discussed in [How to call library function as custom function from spreadsheet formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616415/how-to-call-library-function-as-custom-function-from-spreadsheet-formula) and  [How to call a library function from a spreadsheet drop-down menu generated by the same library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716355/how-to-call-a-library-function-from-a-spreadsheet-drop-down-menu-generated-by-th)

The tl;dr is that you wrap the library function in another function.

/**

- @customfunction
  */

```
function TheCustomFormula(input) {
    MyLibrary.MyCustomFormula(input)
}
```

Then use the wrapping function to call the formula in the sheet.

```
=TheCustomFormula(input)
```